# JS. При использовании Math.pow(10,X) при значениях X = -4 , -5 получившееся число перестает округляться

Tags: javascript

JS. При использовании Math.pow(10,X) при значениях X = -4 и X = -5 получившееся число перестает округляться, и после цифры с порядковым номером X справа от запятой, идут девятки , например (10,-4) даст периодическое число 0.0000999(9) а не 0.0001

```
let z = Math.pow(10,-4);
console.log(z);
```

Пожалуйста объясните почему так происходит. Понимаю, то что можно дописать округление и т.д. Но все же почему js выдает мне периодическое число, а не точное.

Comment: @Grundy Немного ведь отличается от того вопроса, т.к. если прямо написать `1 / 10000`, выводит `0.0001`. Получается, дело в коде pow, а не IEEE 754 (точнее, и то, и другое)